# Package Manage Console not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, nuget

I am trying to install Npgsql and Npgsql.EntityFramework and getting this error:

```
Install-Package : The remote name could not be resolved: 'www.nuget.org'
At line:1 char:16
+ Install-Package <<<<  Npgsql
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], WebException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

What am I doing wrong? Please help

Comment: Can you reach www.nuget.org from your browser?  It's quite possible you're having a network/proxy issue.

Comment: @DavidL yes I can reach it from my browser

Comment: What is the package source set to in Package Manager -> Package Manager Sources -> Package Settings?

Comment: It is https://nuget.org/api/v2/ @DavidL

Comment: Give https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/ a try (if you hover over the link, you'll see that it resolves to www, whereas your current link doesn't)

Comment: @DavidL same thing :( seems like it is indeed a network error

Comment: Bummer.  I'm out of ideas.  Good luck with it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK this is stupid.

Rebooting my laptop actually helped!

Must have been some wifi network error

Comment: In retrospect, it may have actually been that the newest version of Nuget required an update.  Updating the Nuget plugin via Tools -> Extensions and Updates